# What is the noun that describes the urge to harm someone?

Tags: nouns

I am writing about the character Roger in William Golding's *Lord of the Flies*. If you have read the book, you would know that this character is one with an urge to harm other people.

So my question is whether there is suitable single word for "urge to harm someone"?

Answer (score 6):

This book is an all-time classic. I hope that you read the whole thing, and pay attention.

The word you are looking for is:

**spite**

See the definition over at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/spite).

On a side note, the main antagonist is *Jack* from Lord of the Flies and is probably the one you speak of who is harboring the spite against the protagonist *Ralph*.

Comment: The link may have many definitions. It would be helpful if you could quote the intended definition here itself. :)

Answer (score 5):

Consider, ***malevolence***

> the quality or state of being malevolent
>
> malevolent
>
> : having or showing a desire to cause harm to another person
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malevolent)

Also, ***malignancy***

> malignant
>
> :  passionately and relentlessly malevolent :  aggressively malicious
>
> [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/malignant)

Answer (score 4):

The term you are looking for seems to be ***vindictiveness***.

If you wanted to present this urge as a simple, non-directed feature of the character, then ***[spite](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spite)*** might be what you want:  general-purpose destructiveness against *anyone* sufficiently vulnerable, or as Merriam-Webster has it, ‘petty ill will or hatred with the disposition to irritate, annoy, or thwart’.  This would be an urge to harm anyone at all just because you can, and because that satisfies something in you.  It is close to the idea of [***bullying*** or ***browbeating***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bullying): doing harm for the sake of it, like Alex and his droogs celebrating ‘ultraviolence’ in *[A Clockwork Orange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Clockwork_Orange)*.  The destructive act is the important thing:  it doesn’t matter who the victim is.

However, if you want to discuss this urge as being in some sense *motivated*, or even (in the character's mind) *justified*, then *[**vindictiveness**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vindictive)* is the term: ‘having or showing a desire to hurt someone who has hurt or caused problems for you’.  This is an intent to harm a *particular* person for (in your mind) a *particular* reason.

It is close to the meaning of ***[vengefulness](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vengeful)***, but that is more to do with settling a score or righting a specific wrong.  *Vindictiveness* emphasises *the desire to harm*, within that.

Answer (score 0):

- 5¢ word: ***evil***
- 10¢ word: ***malice***
- $10 words: [***psychopathy***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy) and [***sociopathy***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychopathy#Sociopathy)

  > It may be the case the psychopathy is usually genetic,
  > while sociopathy is the result of extremely negative experience.
  >                 — [about.com](http://bipolar.about.com/od/glossarys/g/gl_sociopath.htm)